# How To Select Start Date And End Date Based On Days Check Box In Ionic 2?

Tags: html, css, datepicker, ionic2

I'm developing an Ionic 2 Application, How to select start date and end date based on clicking of `days check box`, actually i want to schedule a repeat event between `Start Date` to `End Date`, **For Example:-** if i select `Saturday` and `Sunday` as checkbox between `start date` and `end date`, i would like to return all Saturdays and Sundays between those selected dates

[My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/j3eJhC1VTjSiHhU2elQM?p=preview)

**My Code:-**

```
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-10>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-13>
      <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>Sunday</ion-label>

    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-13>
       <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>Monday</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-13>
       <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>Tuesday</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-13>
        <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>Wednesday</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-13>
        <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>Thursday</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-13>
        <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>Friday</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10>
       <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>Saturday</ion-label>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col width-15>

    </ion-col>


</ion-row>

 <ion-row align='center'>

    <ion-col width-50>
        <button ion-button outline class="floatR">Start Date<ion-datetime  displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MM YYYY"></ion-datetime></button>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col width-50>
        <button ion-button outline class="floatL">End Date <ion-datetime  displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MM YYYY" ></ion-datetime></button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

 <ion-row align='center'>

    <ion-col width-50>
        <button ion-button outline class="floatR">Start Time<ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" pickerFormat="h mm A"></ion-datetime></button>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col width-50>
        <button ion-button outline class="floatL">End Time <ion-datetime  displayFormat="h:mm A" pickerFormat="h mm A"></ion-datetime></button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

- Please look into my plunker and help us, please if knows the answer update my plunker as well to know the exact solution...thanks...

Answer (score 0):

1- from your checkbox create an array of days(form 0 to 6)
for example

```
var selectedWeekDays=[0,1,2];
```

2- use this method to calculate all days:

```
calcSelectedDays(startDate, endDate, selectedWeekDays) {
   if (startDate > endDate) return false;
   var date  = startDate;
   var dates = [];

   while (date < endDate) {
      if(selectedWeekDays.indexOf(date.getDay()) != -1){
         dates.push(new Date(date));
      }
      date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
   }

    return dates;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, can you please update the plunker as well to know the exact solution, bcoz we have some confusion , then in html part what are the thinks need to be add ?, thanks for helping to us....

Comment: my friend, you just need some basic logic to complete the task. you can find them in every tutorial. you need to get values from check boxes and make an array. try to do it yourself, and if you stuck any where you can ask again.